# FancyBox linking to another page with image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Ive never used fancy box before and i cannot get it to do anything but open a new window with the image in it, I would like it to open in the same page using the 'elastic' feature, 
this is what i have written...

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="grid_5" id="images">
            <a id="single_image" href="htmlandcss/images/1car.gif"><img src="htmlandcss/images/1car.gif" alt=""/></a>
</div>  

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  

                        $("a#single_image").fancybox({
                            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                            'transitionOut' :   'elastic', 
                            'overlayShow'   :   false
                        });

                    });

    </script>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Is Fancybox loading in? Try calling .fancybox without any options, see if it loads then.

Comment: when i take out...   

'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
'transitionOut' :   'elastic', 
'overlayShow'   :   false

it works the same by going to another page, firebug says that fancybox is not a function does that mean its not being loaded in?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The Fancybox isn't showing? Also try `$("#single_image")`, you don't need to specify the `a` since an id should be unique in your page anyway.

Comment: Yes fancybox isnt showing i just get directed to another page with the image on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of jQuery you're using is incompatible with Fancybox2 - I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'
```

Try updating your jQuery to latest, or at least 1.6.4 (which [definitely works](http://jsfiddle.net/VfLsv/5/))

Comment: I think he's using the Fancybox 1 since there doesn't seem to be a `transitionIn` `transitionOut` option in Fancybox 2.

Comment: Yeah, I saw them too after. But the online doc mention `openEffect` and `closeEffect` but it looks like `transiontionIn` and `transitionOut` still works.

Comment: I have went and checked i have everything up to date, and i have got it to work in firefox and chrome but IE still refuse to work

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one is you need, more simple and short code

```
$.fancybox.open([
{
    href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
    link : 'http://jquery.com/'}
],{
    afterShow: function() {
    $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="' + this.link + '" />')
    },   

    padding : 0   
});
```